# Android : forwarding of packets to an IP address

Tags: android, networking, iptables

I have an Android device. I need to forward packets arriving at the external IP to an internal IP to which Android is connected to.

I would like to know if I can write an App to enable this forwarding.

Also, if this doesn't what is the conventional way this is done. If I should use some scripts where should I place them??

And oh, can I test this using an android emulator??

Thanks.

Comment: Related to the tag iptables you know that this command is only permitted for system applications/rooted phones?

Answer (score 0):

It is may be possible to emulate a behavior like port forwarding but not routing for non rooted devices.

Also if you want to forward traffic from the mobile network to the wlan this is so far I know not possible. Android switches the connetion between mobile network and wlan. It is not possible to use both. Except some hot spot use cases.

Comment: Just to clarify, when I said I would like to test it on an emulator, I meant using a network script in my android sources and start an emulator on it. I would prefer the App way though. But yes, I guess I cannot have root access :(

Comment: Do you mean that you want to start a android app from a console?

Comment: No. When I talked about emulator, it was only to test a script to set iptable rules.

Comment: Btw, how about App firewalls like Droidwall. How are they getting root access?? Are these firewall apps not downloadable from App stores? How are they allowed root permission to change ipdatble rules?

Comment: Droidwall and co need a rooted phone. There are depending on your divice serveral options to unlock/root your device. As far I know all apps which desire root access need to ask the user thrue a special app called sudo.apk. But I'm not absolutly sure.

Comment: Btw isn't iptables a user level utility to access the Netfilter. Why would we need root access?

Comment: In the android security system restrict the access to many commands for root. So is e.g. the access to vi also restricted for root too.